# How to play ts file using the cache in the AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-live-streaming

I want to cache the HLS in the ts file.
Apple demo site use custom schema for this site.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc1791/Introduction/Intro.html

This sample use custom schema. But it's use redirect for ts file.
I searched "How to play ts file using the cache in the AVPlayer". I found use redirect local proxy. But it method is prohibited to Apple that the move  background.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2277/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010841-CH1-SUBSECTION2

Is it possible to start the ts file cached locally on the AVPlayer ?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Its not possible to play ts files directly using iOS Player (AVPlayer).
But there is a way to play it.

1. Download the .ts file and save it in app document directory.
2. Use this library [Keemotion/TS2MP4](https://github.com/Keemotion/TS2MP4) to
   convert ts file to mp4 which can be played using AVPlayer.

Now you can either do it discreetly downloading -> convert -> play for each single file. 
or You can download multiple -> convert them to one large mp4 file and play it.